# Stack 2 y values into stacked bar graph with error bars in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

In R, I am trying to make a stacked bar graph with separate values from two different data columns with error bars. But I am unable to find how to create a graph with two y values stacked on top of each other. So in the case of the data below, I have two separate yields (from different species). There would be 3 bars (each treatment), with mean yield 2 stacked on top of mean yield 1 with error bars for each yield 1 and yield 2. Any ideas how to do this?

| Treatment | Yield1 | Yield2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 400 | 70 |
| 1 | 370 | 30 |
| 1 | 390 | 90 |
| 2 | 275 | 10 |
| 2 | 300 | 12 |
| 2 | 280 | 17 |
| 3 | 70 | 150 |
| 3 | 125 | 130 |
| 3 | 100 | 130 |

Obviously I can make a bar graph with a single yield

```
p<- ggbarplot(df, x="Treatment", y="Yield1", add="mean_se")
```

but how to I stack Yield2 bars on top?

Comment: I my opinion stacking "dynamite bars" is not a good approach. How about just grouping them.

Answer (score 0):

The first step when you have multiple columns is to reshape your data to long or tidy format. Doing so you get a column with values which could be mapped on `y` and a column with the categories which could be mapped on `fill`. Additionally to get the right order of the stack I converted the `name` column to a `factor` for which I used `forcats::fct_rev` to reverse the order.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggpubr)

df <- data.frame(
  Treatment = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
  Yield1 = c(400L, 370L, 390L, 275L, 300L, 280L, 70L, 125L, 100L),
  Yield2 = c(70L, 30L, 90L, 10L, 12L, 17L, 150L, 130L, 130L)
)

df |>
  pivot_longer(-Treatment) |>
  mutate(name = forcats::fct_rev(name)) |>
  ggbarplot(x = "Treatment", y = "value", fill = "name", add = "mean_se")
```

[image]

Of course could we achieve the same result using `ggplot2` which however requires more effort as stacking errorbars isn't that easy. As a consequence getting the same result requires to manually do the stacking for the error bars by computing the cumulative sum:

```r
df |>
  pivot_longer(-Treatment) |>
  group_by(Treatment, name) |>
  summarise(mean_se(value)) |>
  mutate(across(-name, list(cum = cumsum)), name = forcats::fct_rev(name)) |>
  ggplot(aes(Treatment, y, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ymin_cum, ymax = ymax_cum), width = .25)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Treatment'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
```

[image]